# If $X$ is standard normal, is $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\mathbb{E}[f(-X)]$ for any function $f$?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

I know if $X$ has a standard normal distribution then so does $-X$. 
Is it true that $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\mathbb{E}[f(-X)]$ for any function $f$?

Comment: Translation: does the expectation of any function of a random variable depend on the distribution of that random variable, or could it depend on additional factors?  When the question is posed like this, perhaps the answer becomes very clear.

Comment: Yes, and more generally, this is true for any random variable whose density function is symmetric

Comment: I edited the title - "I have a question" is really not informative (presumably every OP has a question)  and to be accurate, the question was not asking about expectations of standard normal, but expectations of functions of standard normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's true that if $X\sim N(0,1)$ then $E[f(X)]=E[f(-X)]$ for any function $f$.

Why? Well, if $Z$ is a random variable with associated probability density function $\phi$, then $E[f(Z)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z)\phi(z)dz$. Now $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution, so they have the same probability density function, so (taking $Z=X$ and $Z=-X$) it must be the case that $E[f(X)]=E[f(-X)]$.